# Ajax ModalPopup Extender with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, modalpopupextender

I am trying to implement an Ajax ModalPopup Extender but i have no clue where to start.
Can someone please show me how to go about doing this or at least guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently used JQuery to send modal popups.  Take a look at this.  Seems pretty easy to use.

http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how happy the AJAX Control Toolkit is with MVC (I'm not an MVC user), but if you're looking for information regarding the use of the control, watch this video. It's super easy to implement:

[video](http://www.asp.net/learn/ajax-videos/video-85.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think controls from the Ajax Control Toolkit are fully compatible with ASP.NET MVC.  The Ajax Control Toolkit widgets are implemented similarly to traditional web controls, so most probably require viewstate, which does not exist in ASP.NET MVC.

For accomplishing modal in ASP.NET MVC, you'll have to go old school and take a more bare-metal approach and start hacking angle brackets, JavaScript, and CSS.  What I've used in the past is a jQuery plugin [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/), but there plenty out there.